# How to fix this bazel project for kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, bazel

I want to be able to use bazel to organize a simple kotlin project.

I am using the templates as listed in rules_kotlin (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin)

This is my BUILD file

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kt_jvm_library")

kt_jvm_library(
    name = "redis-tools",
    srcs = glob(["*.kt"]),
    deps = [],
)
```

This is my WORKSPACE file

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

rules_kotlin_version = "legacy-1.3.0"
rules_kotlin_sha = "4fd769fb0db5d3c6240df8a9500515775101964eebdf85a3f9f0511130885fde"
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_kotlin",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/archive/%s.zip" % rules_kotlin_version],
    type = "zip",
    strip_prefix = "rules_kotlin-%s" % rules_kotlin_version,
    sha256 = rules_kotlin_sha,
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kotlin_repositories", "kt_register_toolchains")
kotlin_repositories() # if you want the default. Otherwise see custom kotlinc distribution below
kt_register_toolchains() # to use the default toolchain, otherwise see toolchains below
```

My kotlin file `main.kt`:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    // Creates a reader instance which takes
    // input from standard input - keyboard
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    print("Enter a number: ")

    // nextInt() reads the next integer from the keyboard
    var integer:Int = reader.nextInt()

    // println() prints the following line to the output screen
    println("You entered: $integer")
}
```

I use a very simple file to test my setup.

Without bazel, I can do these to build: `kotlinc main.kt -include-runtime -d test.jar`

then run it with `java -jar test.jar`

When I use `bazel build .`, bazel creates a few folders. I tried to run `java -jar bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/redis-tools.jar` but it failed.

```
$ java -jar bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/redis-tools.jar
no main manifest attribute, in bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/redis-tools.jar
```

Did I miss a target? How can I run the `main.tk` from the bazel output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar you are trying to run is missing a manifest file which declares its main class.

For executing a binary, Bazel uses a shell script wrapper which includes  the required jvm flags and its run-time dependencies.

Notice that you are using `kt_jvm_library`. This rule builds a shared dependency without the wrapper. To include a wrapper you should use the `kt_jvm_binary` rule. Then you can specify the main class by setting the `main_class` attribute.

Notice that you can use the `bazel run :redis-tools` to run the jar (use `-s` to see which script Bazel excuted)

You can also use `bazel build :redis-tools_deploy.jar` to build a "fat-jar" which will include the manifest.